# SVG Clock - Transform origin not working on the lancets

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I am trying to reproduce something that I saw a while ago which is animating an SVG clock. Everything works fine but I can't get around the transform-origin which seems not to be working... is the way the path is made?

```js
// Real time clock animation

let sec = document.querySelector('.seconds-lancet');
let min = document.querySelector('.minutes-lancet');
let hour = document.querySelector('.hours-lancet');

setInterval(function() {
  let d = new Date();
  function r(el, deg) {
    el.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ deg +')');
  }
  r(sec, 6*d.getSeconds());
  r(min, 6*d.getMinutes());
  r(hour, 30*(d.getHours()%12) + d.getMinutes()/2);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.seconds-lancet,
.minutes-lancet,
.hours-lancet {
  transform-origin: bottom center !important;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 621.07 768">
      <g id="clock">
        <circle cx="70.64" cy="107.54" r="41.2" fill="#cdcfd0" opacity=".81" transform="rotate(-80.78 70.641 107.542)"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M112.62 99.31c0-19-14.55-34.39-32.5-34.39s-32.5 15.4-32.5 34.39v8.42l64.45 1.21z"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M116.79 114l-74.17-1.39v-13.3c0-21.72 16.83-39.39 37.5-39.39s37.5 17.67 37.5 39.39v.28zm-64.17-11.18l54.74 1 .26-4.68c-.07-16.14-12.38-29.22-27.5-29.22s-27.5 13.18-27.5 29.39z"/>
        <circle cx="80.29" cy="107.1" r="34.38" fill="#fff"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M80.29 145a37.93 37.93 0 1 1 37.93-37.93A38 38 0 0 1 80.29 145zm0-68.77a30.84 30.84 0 1 0 30.84 30.84 30.88 30.88 0 0 0-30.84-30.81z"/>
        <path fill="#ffffff" d="M80.29 138.14a31.07 31.07 0 1 1 12.09-59.7A31.18 31.18 0 0 1 108.92 95a31 31 0 0 1-6.66 34 31.2 31.2 0 0 1-9.88 6.66 30.87 30.87 0 0 1-12.09 2.48z"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M77.29 84.72l-.67.2h-.21a.5.5 0 0 1-.12-1l1-.32a2.14 2.14 0 0 1 .56-.1.56.56 0 0 1 .57.57v5.51a.57.57 0 1 1-1.14 0zM80 89.05l2-1.71c.89-.75 1.22-1.17 1.22-1.76a1 1 0 0 0-1-1 1.61 1.61 0 0 0-1.29.72.49.49 0 0 1-.4.18A.52.52 0 0 1 80 85a.63.63 0 0 1 .13-.36 2.53 2.53 0 0 1 2.16-1 2 2 0 0 1 2.15 1.95c0 1-.54 1.58-1.69 2.52l-1.34 1.12H84a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3.7a.55.55 0 0 1-.61-.54.68.68 0 0 1 .31-.64zM99.72 109.68a.59.59 0 0 1 .8-.86 2.12 2.12 0 0 0 1.59.66 1.09 1.09 0 0 0 1.21-1c0-.68-.63-1.06-1.61-1.06h-.25a.53.53 0 0 1-.53-.52.66.66 0 0 1 .26-.49l1.64-1.73h-2.54a.53.53 0 0 1-.54-.52.54.54 0 0 1 .54-.53h3.58a.55.55 0 0 1 .6.53.86.86 0 0 1-.35.66l-1.64 1.68c1.06.13 2 .66 2 1.93a2.21 2.21 0 0 1-2.44 2.18 3.31 3.31 0 0 1-2.32-.93zM78.51 129.87a3.16 3.16 0 0 1-.79-2.48c0-2 .94-3.53 2.78-3.53a2.83 2.83 0 0 1 1.63.46.55.55 0 0 1 .28.49.54.54 0 0 1-.54.53.55.55 0 0 1-.29-.08 1.94 1.94 0 0 0-1.12-.36c-1 0-1.5.87-1.56 2.06a2.26 2.26 0 0 1 3.83 1.39 2.26 2.26 0 0 1-2.41 2.21 2.39 2.39 0 0 1-1.81-.69zm3.08-1.48a1.34 1.34 0 0 0-2.65 0 1.22 1.22 0 0 0 1.35 1.16 1.17 1.17 0 0 0 1.3-1.16zM57.16 109.89a.53.53 0 0 1-.26-.47.52.52 0 0 1 .54-.52.63.63 0 0 1 .31.09 1.94 1.94 0 0 0 1.19.4c1 0 1.53-.84 1.57-2A1.93 1.93 0 0 1 59 108a2.06 2.06 0 0 1-2.3-2.06 2.26 2.26 0 0 1 2.42-2.25 2.4 2.4 0 0 1 1.81.69 3.3 3.3 0 0 1 .78 2.48c0 2.08-1 3.53-2.79 3.53a2.94 2.94 0 0 1-1.76-.5zm3.31-4a1.23 1.23 0 0 0-1.35-1.19 1.19 1.19 0 0 0-1.29 1.2 1.18 1.18 0 0 0 1.32 1.16 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 1.32-1.15z"/>
        <rect width="2.32" height=".98" x="51.17" y="106.63" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M80.91 80c0 .24-.17.36-.41.36h-.2a.33.33 0 0 1-.37-.36v-1.51c0-.23.13-.49.37-.49h.2a.47.47 0 0 1 .41.49z"/>
        <rect width="2.32" height=".98" x="106.97" y="106.63" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <rect width=".98" height="2.32" x="79.93" y="133.68" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M65.73 131.33a.4.4 0 0 0 .11.53.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11l.63-1a.38.38 0 0 0-.11-.53.38.38 0 0 0-.53.11zM55.6 120.8a.39.39 0 0 0-.15.52.39.39 0 0 0 .52.15l1-.56a.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52.39.39 0 0 0-.53-.15zM56 92.41a.38.38 0 0 0-.53.11.4.4 0 0 0 .11.53l1 .63a.39.39 0 0 0 .53-.11.37.37 0 0 0-.11-.53zM66.49 82.28a.37.37 0 0 0-.52-.15.38.38 0 0 0-.14.52l.55 1a.38.38 0 0 0 .52.15.37.37 0 0 0 .15-.52zM94.86 82.79a.38.38 0 0 0-.11-.53.38.38 0 0 0-.53.1l-.63 1a.37.37 0 0 0 .11.53.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11zM105 93.32a.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52.37.37 0 0 0-.52-.15l-1 .56a.38.38 0 0 0-.14.52.38.38 0 0 0 .52.14zM104.63 121.58a.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11.39.39 0 0 0-.11-.53l-1-.63a.37.37 0 0 0-.53.11.38.38 0 0 0 .11.53zM94.1 131.71a.39.39 0 0 0 .52.15.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52l-.56-1a.38.38 0 0 0-.52-.14.37.37 0 0 0-.15.52z"/>
        <g id="hands">
          <path class="minutes-lancet" fill="#2e2c2b" d="M81.26 107h-1.93l.3-30.58c0-.23.25-.42.56-.42.31 0 .56.19.56.42z"/>
          <path class="hours-lancet" fill="#2e2c2b" d="M81.48 107h-2.3l.35-22.69c0-.17.31-.31.67-.31.37 0 .67.14.67.31z"/>
          <path class="seconds-lancet" fill="#008048" d="M81.06 109H79.6l.23-32.55a.44.44 0 0 1 .42-.45.45.45 0 0 1 .43.45z"/>
          <circle cx="80.28" cy="107" r="2" fill="#034732"/>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks

Comment: your "rotate" seems off. try `el.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)');`

Comment: in fact, `el.style.transform = 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)';`

Comment: Thanks! But that's wrong. You don't need to specify 'deg' to the setAttribute. If you do you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've assumed that the transform-box is the fill-box, it's not by default it's the view-box. Setting transform-box: fill-box; seems to make things work better.

```js
// Real time clock animation

let sec = document.querySelector('.seconds-lancet');
let min = document.querySelector('.minutes-lancet');
let hour = document.querySelector('.hours-lancet');

setInterval(function() {
  let d = new Date();
  function r(el, deg) {
    el.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ deg +')');
  }
  r(sec, 6*d.getSeconds());
  r(min, 6*d.getMinutes());
  r(hour, 30*(d.getHours()%12) + d.getMinutes()/2);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.seconds-lancet,
.minutes-lancet,
.hours-lancet {
  transform-origin: bottom center !important;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 621.07 768">
      <g id="clock">
        <circle cx="70.64" cy="107.54" r="41.2" fill="#cdcfd0" opacity=".81" transform="rotate(-80.78 70.641 107.542)"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M112.62 99.31c0-19-14.55-34.39-32.5-34.39s-32.5 15.4-32.5 34.39v8.42l64.45 1.21z"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M116.79 114l-74.17-1.39v-13.3c0-21.72 16.83-39.39 37.5-39.39s37.5 17.67 37.5 39.39v.28zm-64.17-11.18l54.74 1 .26-4.68c-.07-16.14-12.38-29.22-27.5-29.22s-27.5 13.18-27.5 29.39z"/>
        <circle cx="80.29" cy="107.1" r="34.38" fill="#fff"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M80.29 145a37.93 37.93 0 1 1 37.93-37.93A38 38 0 0 1 80.29 145zm0-68.77a30.84 30.84 0 1 0 30.84 30.84 30.88 30.88 0 0 0-30.84-30.81z"/>
        <path fill="#ffffff" d="M80.29 138.14a31.07 31.07 0 1 1 12.09-59.7A31.18 31.18 0 0 1 108.92 95a31 31 0 0 1-6.66 34 31.2 31.2 0 0 1-9.88 6.66 30.87 30.87 0 0 1-12.09 2.48z"/>
        <path fill="#034732" d="M77.29 84.72l-.67.2h-.21a.5.5 0 0 1-.12-1l1-.32a2.14 2.14 0 0 1 .56-.1.56.56 0 0 1 .57.57v5.51a.57.57 0 1 1-1.14 0zM80 89.05l2-1.71c.89-.75 1.22-1.17 1.22-1.76a1 1 0 0 0-1-1 1.61 1.61 0 0 0-1.29.72.49.49 0 0 1-.4.18A.52.52 0 0 1 80 85a.63.63 0 0 1 .13-.36 2.53 2.53 0 0 1 2.16-1 2 2 0 0 1 2.15 1.95c0 1-.54 1.58-1.69 2.52l-1.34 1.12H84a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3.7a.55.55 0 0 1-.61-.54.68.68 0 0 1 .31-.64zM99.72 109.68a.59.59 0 0 1 .8-.86 2.12 2.12 0 0 0 1.59.66 1.09 1.09 0 0 0 1.21-1c0-.68-.63-1.06-1.61-1.06h-.25a.53.53 0 0 1-.53-.52.66.66 0 0 1 .26-.49l1.64-1.73h-2.54a.53.53 0 0 1-.54-.52.54.54 0 0 1 .54-.53h3.58a.55.55 0 0 1 .6.53.86.86 0 0 1-.35.66l-1.64 1.68c1.06.13 2 .66 2 1.93a2.21 2.21 0 0 1-2.44 2.18 3.31 3.31 0 0 1-2.32-.93zM78.51 129.87a3.16 3.16 0 0 1-.79-2.48c0-2 .94-3.53 2.78-3.53a2.83 2.83 0 0 1 1.63.46.55.55 0 0 1 .28.49.54.54 0 0 1-.54.53.55.55 0 0 1-.29-.08 1.94 1.94 0 0 0-1.12-.36c-1 0-1.5.87-1.56 2.06a2.26 2.26 0 0 1 3.83 1.39 2.26 2.26 0 0 1-2.41 2.21 2.39 2.39 0 0 1-1.81-.69zm3.08-1.48a1.34 1.34 0 0 0-2.65 0 1.22 1.22 0 0 0 1.35 1.16 1.17 1.17 0 0 0 1.3-1.16zM57.16 109.89a.53.53 0 0 1-.26-.47.52.52 0 0 1 .54-.52.63.63 0 0 1 .31.09 1.94 1.94 0 0 0 1.19.4c1 0 1.53-.84 1.57-2A1.93 1.93 0 0 1 59 108a2.06 2.06 0 0 1-2.3-2.06 2.26 2.26 0 0 1 2.42-2.25 2.4 2.4 0 0 1 1.81.69 3.3 3.3 0 0 1 .78 2.48c0 2.08-1 3.53-2.79 3.53a2.94 2.94 0 0 1-1.76-.5zm3.31-4a1.23 1.23 0 0 0-1.35-1.19 1.19 1.19 0 0 0-1.29 1.2 1.18 1.18 0 0 0 1.32 1.16 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 1.32-1.15z"/>
        <rect width="2.32" height=".98" x="51.17" y="106.63" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M80.91 80c0 .24-.17.36-.41.36h-.2a.33.33 0 0 1-.37-.36v-1.51c0-.23.13-.49.37-.49h.2a.47.47 0 0 1 .41.49z"/>
        <rect width="2.32" height=".98" x="106.97" y="106.63" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <rect width=".98" height="2.32" x="79.93" y="133.68" fill="#008048" rx=".43" ry=".43"/>
        <path fill="#008048" d="M65.73 131.33a.4.4 0 0 0 .11.53.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11l.63-1a.38.38 0 0 0-.11-.53.38.38 0 0 0-.53.11zM55.6 120.8a.39.39 0 0 0-.15.52.39.39 0 0 0 .52.15l1-.56a.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52.39.39 0 0 0-.53-.15zM56 92.41a.38.38 0 0 0-.53.11.4.4 0 0 0 .11.53l1 .63a.39.39 0 0 0 .53-.11.37.37 0 0 0-.11-.53zM66.49 82.28a.37.37 0 0 0-.52-.15.38.38 0 0 0-.14.52l.55 1a.38.38 0 0 0 .52.15.37.37 0 0 0 .15-.52zM94.86 82.79a.38.38 0 0 0-.11-.53.38.38 0 0 0-.53.1l-.63 1a.37.37 0 0 0 .11.53.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11zM105 93.32a.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52.37.37 0 0 0-.52-.15l-1 .56a.38.38 0 0 0-.14.52.38.38 0 0 0 .52.14zM104.63 121.58a.38.38 0 0 0 .53-.11.39.39 0 0 0-.11-.53l-1-.63a.37.37 0 0 0-.53.11.38.38 0 0 0 .11.53zM94.1 131.71a.39.39 0 0 0 .52.15.39.39 0 0 0 .15-.52l-.56-1a.38.38 0 0 0-.52-.14.37.37 0 0 0-.15.52z"/>
        <g id="hands">
          <path class="minutes-lancet" fill="#2e2c2b" d="M81.26 107h-1.93l.3-30.58c0-.23.25-.42.56-.42.31 0 .56.19.56.42z"/>
          <path class="hours-lancet" fill="#2e2c2b" d="M81.48 107h-2.3l.35-22.69c0-.17.31-.31.67-.31.37 0 .67.14.67.31z"/>
          <path class="seconds-lancet" fill="#008048" d="M81.06 109H79.6l.23-32.55a.44.44 0 0 1 .42-.45.45.45 0 0 1 .43.45z"/>
          <circle cx="80.28" cy="107" r="2" fill="#034732"/>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! You saved my day! I have completely forgot about that and I thought already tried. Thanks a lot again!

What do you use as fallback for this property which is currently not supported in IE and Safari? Is there an alternative way to achieve this when you have a big SVG scene because what I have put is only a small element of a big scene. Thanks!